# Do users like/read changelogs("What's new" dialogs)?

Tags: user-expectation, dialog, changelog

When I update my app(with bug fixes, new features, removed features etc), I present the user with a dialog like this:

[image]

Does the user actually read it? Will they find the dialog annoying? Will the user want to know about this information at all?

I'm not asking specifically for Android, this question applies on any platform.

I'm a programmer so when I see a changelog, I read it and feel happy because the software I'm using is getting better. I'm not sure about the general public.

Comment: I know you state you're not asking specificly about android, but in android this information is already on the play store listing. So is your question about having *somewhere* but not shoved in their face vs showing it in a dialogue on next app open

Comment: @RichardTingle The Play Store only shows the changelog for the very latest version, right? So if you release frequently and/or the user only launches the app occasionally, they might miss something. Also, getting to the page for the app in the Play Store is a major hassle that few users will go through.

Answer (score 3):

Surfacing new features and 'discoverability' in general are major UX challenges. Don't expect a change log (or any other approach) to completely handle this for you. Users can and will ignore even outrageous modal dialogs. As a general goal, you should strive to make new features naturally apparent to users... sometimes easier said than done.

For a change-log [or any surfacing strategy], ask if it's appropriate to your users and your app. Will the change log appear to all users? Will they all be interested in the changes? Do the users actually *need* this information? Is the strategy's cost in irritation and delay outweighed by the benefit in user education?

People are very used to clicking past terms and conditions screens at app start. I'd be pessimistic about a change log screen getting much attention.

Comment: I'd like to add that sometimes change-logs *are* appropriate, e.g. for "beta" versions of apps where most of the users are eager to hear about new updates. There also tend to be more engineering-type people using beta software than there are for more mainstream apps.